# Scipy cubic interpolation returns NaN

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following parameters:

```py
import numpy
import scipy

s = 2.8353126768180923

speed = numpy.array(
     [ 1.02119705,  2.04239409,  3.06359114,  4.08478819,  5.10598524,
       6.12718228,  7.14837933,  8.16957638,  9.19077343, 10.25490073,
       11.3278126 , 12.4095641 , 13.50021059, 14.59980773, 15.64265114,
       16.68549455, 17.72833796, 18.77118137, 19.81402478, 20.85686819,
       21.8997116 , 22.94255501, 23.98539842, 25.        , 25.        ])

power = numpy.array(
     [ 0. ,    3.6,   29.9,   98.2,  208.3,  384.3,  637. ,  975.8,
       1403.6, 1817.8, 2088.7, 2237. , 2300. , 2350. , 2350. , 2350. ,
       2350. , 2350. , 2350. , 2350. , 2350. , 2350. , 2350. , 2350. ,
       2350. ])
```

I am trying to execute a cubic and a linear interpolation:

```py
cubic = scipy.interpolate.splev(x=s, tck=scipy.interpolate.splrep(speed, power, k=3))
lin = numpy.interp(s, speed, power)
```

However, the `cubic` interpolation results in NaN.

```py
print(cubic)
    nan

print(lin)
    24.02089607810346
```

What I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The arguments to `splrep` is supposed to be a function representing `y = f(x)`, but you've got `x=2350` twice.  Remove the last element from `speed` and `power` and it runs fine.

Comment: I didn't notice it, following your suggestion it now works without problems. Thanks a lot, @FrankYellin!